# Route from Login.js to Signin.js on click of a button in React

Tags: reactjs

I have a component `Login` I want to navigate to another component `SignUp` as an option from Login other than logging in. How do I implement this?

Here is my Login component:

```
    import React, { useCallback, useContext } from "react"; 
    import {withRouter, Redirect, Router} from "react-router";
    import app from "../../Home/Components/base.js";
    import { AuthContext } from "../../Auth/Components/Auth";
    import { Button, Form, FormGroup, Label, Input} from "reactstrap";
    import '/home/dennis/WebstormProjects/studentsdiscussionforum /node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
    import '/home/dennis/WebstormProjects/studentsdiscussionforum/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js'
    import './Login.css';
    import Link from "react-router-dom/modules/Link";

    const Login = ({ history }) => { 
    const handleLogin = useCallback(
        async event => {
            event.preventDefault();
            const {email, password} = event.target.elements;

            try {
                await app
                    .auth()
                    .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email.value,    password.value);
                history.push("/");

            } catch (error) {
                alert(error);
            }
        },
        [history]
    );


    const {currentUser} = useContext(AuthContext);

    if (currentUser) {
        return <Redirect to="/"/>
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Form className="App" onSubmit={handleLogin}>
            <h1><span className="font-weight-bold">Curious</span>.com</h1>
            <FormGroup>
                <label>
                    Email<br/>
                    <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email"/>
                </label>
            </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup>
                <label>
                    Password<br/>
                    <input name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password"/>
                </label>
            </FormGroup>
                <button className= "btn-dark btn-small" type="submit">Log in</button>
                <br/>
            </Form>
        </div>
    );
    };

    export default withRouter(Login);
```

Here is my SignUp component:

```
 import React, { useCallback } from "react";
    import { withRouter } from "react-router";
    import app from "../../Home/Components/base.js";
    import {Form, FormGroup} from "reactstrap";

    const SignUp = ({ history }) => {
    const handleSignUp = useCallback(async event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const {email, password } = event.target.elements;
        try {
            await app
                .auth()
                .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email.value, password.value);
            history.push("/");
        } catch (error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    }, [history]);

    return (
        <div>
            <Form className="App" onSubmit={handleSignUp}>
                <h1><span className="font-weight- bold">Curious</span>.com</h1>
                <FormGroup>
                    <label>
                        Email<br/>
                        <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email"/>
                    </label>
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup>
                    <label>
                        Password<br/>
                        <input name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password"/>
                    </label>
                </FormGroup>
                <button className= "btn-dark btn-small" type="submit">Sign  Up</button>
            </Form>
        </div>
    );
    };

    export default withRouter(SignUp);
```

And finally here is my app JavaScript file:

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import Home from "./Home/Components/Home";
    import Login from "./Login/Components/Login.js"
    import SignUp from "./SignUp/Components/Signup.js"
    import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
    import {AuthProvider} from "./Auth/Components/Auth";
    import PrivateRoute from "./PrivateRoute/Components/PrivateRoute";


    class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

    }
    render() {
        return (
            //<Home/>
            <AuthProvider>
            <Router>
            <div>
                <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={Home} />
                <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
                <Route exact path="/signup" component={SignUp} />
            </div>
            </Router>
            </AuthProvider>
        );
    }
    }
    export default App;
```

This project is due tomorrow and I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: Have you tried using react-router's [Link](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/custom-link) component?

Comment: yes but i keep getting the following error ./node_modules/react-router-dom/modules/Link.js
SyntaxError: /home/dennis/WebstormProjects/studentsdiscussionforum/node_modules/react-router-dom/modules/Link.js: Unexpected token (59:11)

  57 |     }
  58 | 
> 59 |     return <a {...props} />;
     |            ^
  60 |   }
  61 | );
  62 |

Comment: Please post the code where you are using the Link.

Comment: This is an excerpt from my login component below where i placed the button
            
                <button className= "btn-dark btn-small" type="submit">Log in</button>
                <br/>
            </Form>
            <Link to="/signup">SignUp</Link>
        </div>
    );
};

export default withRouter(Login);

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't tell me much. Your error is pointing to a specific line of code.  Where is this code?  What part of the component is this link in? Please read up on creating a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Rutherford Wonkington sorry about that found the problem using import { Link } from 'react-router-dom' instead of import Link from "react-router-dom/modules/Link"; fixes the problem

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Switch Component right under router.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Router>
            <Switch>
                <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={Home} />
                <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
                <Route exact path="/signup" component={SignUp} />
            </Switch>
            </Router>
```